# Remap Delete Key in Outlook 2016 - Move to Folder

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-outlook, macros, keymap

I'm in an industry where it would be best practice to keep all of my emails, however, they live in either my deleted items once i've actioned them. Currently using Outlook 2016 with Exchange.

Our company is implementing a policy to clear the deleted items folder at the end of each day which is proving an issue.

Is there a macro I can create which remaps the delete key to move the selected item to a specific folder. E.g. "Deleted 2.0 Items"?

Any and all suggestions welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no way to change the behavior of Delete key using macro. According to your description, I'd like to suggest using Quick step so that you can quickly move a message to a specific folder via shortcut keys:

1. Click Home > the more options button in the Quick Steps group > New > Custom:
   [image]
2. Specify a name for the Quick Step, e.g. : Move to Deleted 2.0 Items, select the actions for the quick steps as follows, choose a Shortcut keys for it (For example Ctrl+Shift+1):
   [image]
3. So that you can press Ctrl+Shift+1 rather then Delete to move the folder to the specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA macro for that. For example, this macro may listen for [BeforeDelete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-beforedelete-event-outlook) event of currently selected item and cancel the deletion while moving the item to the desired folder.